# Wrong response from PHP Closure

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

I trying to understand closures more but I cannot get the correct response from the below code. I get a response of 31 instead of 60 for some reason. My aim is to eventually start unit testing closures.

Thanks

```
<?php


class Closuretest
{

    /**
     * Closuretest constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getToken()
    {


            $response = $this->getEntry('abcde', function() {
                return 30;
            }, 30);

        // Return access token
        return $response;
    }


    /**
     * @param $a
     * @param $b
     * @param $c
     * @return mixed
     */
    private function getEntry($a, $b, $c)
    {
        return $b+$c;
    }

}

$testinstance = new Closuretest();

echo $testinstance->getToken();
```

Comment: on `getEntry` method, you are getting the sum of $b and $c. You passed a closure on the second argument so it becomes closure + 30. If you allow notices in your error verbosity you will get a `PHP Notice:  Object of class Closure could not be converted to int` notice, and interprets the closure as 1, that's why you're getting 31.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the function `getEntry()`, `$b` is not an integer, but a function. You need to execute this function by calling `$b()` to get the result:

```
private function getEntry($a, $b, $c)
{
    return $b() + $c; // instead of `$b + $c`
}
```

Here, `$b()` will return 30, and `$c` is equal to 30. So, `getEntry()` will return 60.